# Windows 7 Networking Problem

Tags: windows-7, networking

I'm on a Windows 7 Computer with an additional Windows 7 computer and an XP computer and I keep getting an error: 0x8007046a: "Not enough server storage is available to Process this command" when I try to connect to a share on the Windows XP Computer.  The Windows 7 Computers talk fine as far as Homeroup, etc, but no dice with XP shares.  Additionally this is in a workgroup.

I have searched countless forums including TechNet, tried IRPStackSize, DhcpNodeType, and Uninstalling/Reinstalling File and Printer Sharing for M$ Networks.   Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your Windows 7 machines/users have permissions to the Windows XP share?

Comment: As of now I'm using Simple File Sharing in WinXP, will that not work with Windows 7?

Comment: Ok, I have WinXP Home installed on the computer that I'm trying to access.  I went to folder options, unchecked the "Use Simple File Sharing" box, and restarted.   The sharing dialog box looks no different than before, and I can't find a permissions dialog.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct permission level set.  You can read more about it in the section, "Managing levels of access to shares and to files" at this link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304040

Comment: I just can't find a permissions dialog to set permissions.. is there a way to set permission via cmd?

Answer (score 1):

Ive seen this before in XP Home, if permissions are set correctly its normally because force guest is set on the XP machine.

1. From the command prompt on the Windows XP computer, run Regedit.exe
2. Select the following registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE| SYSTEM | CurrentControlSet | Control | Lsa

3. Change the forceguest DWORD Value data entry to  0
4. Click OK.
5. Exit the registry editor.
6. Restart the Windows XP computer.

Answer (score 0):

"Not enough server storage is available to process this command"

IRPStackSize should be modified/added to the XP registry, use a value of 15 or 20. Reboot XP PC.

> Click Start, and then click Run.
>
> Type regedit and then click OK.
>
> Navigate to the following key:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
>
> In the right pane, double-click the value IRPStackSize. If
>   the value does not exist, then you must create it. To do
>   this, right-click the right pane while in the Parameters
>   folder of the registry. Point to New, and then click DWord
>   Value.
>
> Type IRPStackSize. It is case sensitive, so be
>   careful to type it exactly.
>
> Change the Base to decimal.
>
> In the Value Data box, increase the value by 15 or 20 then click
>   OK.
>
> Close the Registry Editor.
>
> Restart the computer.